# Extending custom type with functions in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript

I have the following type defined:

```js
export type A {
  id: string,
  name: string
}

export const data: A[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Foo' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bar' },
  ...
]
```

Every time I need to access one of the objects within the array, the `.find` method comes in handy:

```js
  const id = ...; // get the ID

  data.find((entry) => entry.id === id)).name
  ...
  data.find((entry) => entry.name === name)).name
```

As the same search occurs in different locations of the code, I'm looking for a way to extend the `data` object and add custom functions such as:

- `findById(id: number)`
- `findByName(name: string)`
- ...

I will be supposed to invoke the function to get the respective array entry:

```js
  ...
  data.findById(1).name;
  ...
  data.findByName('Foo').id;
```

Is there a way to extend the object in typescript without having to extend the native `Object`?

Comment: The type-definition `A` exclusively does target the OP's custom-type, whereas `const data: A[]` _"declares"_ an array type which is allowed to carry only said custom-types as the very array's items. Thus, one does not want an instance of the built-in array type to feature other array method's than the standard ones. But one easily could implement functions that do exactly what the OP wants them to do, and which each accept an array of said custom-type items as these function's first argument. The usage then changes to ... `findById(data, 1).name` ... or ... `findByName(data, 'Foo').id`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.assign()` to assign extra methods to the array..

`Array.find` can return undefined, so this gets passed on.  An alternative to not returning undefined, is you could throw an exception instead, but that is something you will need to decide on.

eg.

```
type A = {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

const data: A[] & { 
  findById: (id:number) => A | undefined,
  findByName: (name:string) => A | undefined
} 
=  Object.assign([
  { id: 1, name: 'Foo' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bar' },
], { 
  findById: (id:number) => data.find(a => id === a.id),
  findByName: (name:string) => data.find(a => name === a.name)
})

console.log(data.findById(1)?.name);
console.log(data.findByName('Foo')?.id);

//remember find can return undefined
console.log(data.findById(3));
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCWATAXFAdgK4C2ARhAE4A0aBAhsRHgM7AUb4DmKAviigGMA9vlZQsdYHTwwA2gF0oAMmRRaAMw5YAQiACSuKAApsOImUoBKBAD5YUAD5RC%20LBE34IWGug86QAHIMTMb4wTis7FzW8HZwTi5uHl68aohQAPKkAFYQAsAAdHTMzBic%20EaytEiYhgCMVPSMeADkAGJCQi1QPD6qplAATI1hzVAt2nQU3b0o8o01Glq6BngmuObkFDF2ElIFfkZ0trUI8Ih0BdiWfX66QWNGo0yRHJw74pKXh8exTdDnC4FZ6WXigwQiZhCAA2EAK0KEnCMe2%20y30WCMdUsAH5gcFLABuCGiGFwhFIlEHNEPCBGdqdFo4q5YQn8AD0bIoEEYFgoUD8UAEdHwUC5wEIFBFiXcHBSwhJsPhiORXyprhWGIAzJZWfwgA)

Comment: The catch here is that if the `data` object changes – it's used in a React context state –, those functions must be also reassigned. I can probably define an `extend` function that automatically extends the object on every state change but I feel it as a hack more than a proper solution...

Comment: @lucio  There are ways in React to NOT re-create an array every time, I'll often do this if the array is very large, doing `[...old, {}]` can something be wastfull , with you wanting to extend the object, you might find that idea works for you too.